# Environment NiceTabular undefined

Tags: updating, nicematrix

I'm trying to get an example from the manual compiled, but somehow my environment does not recognize `NiceTabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cwc{2cm}wc{3cm}c}
    rose & tulip & daisy & dahlia \\
    violet
    & \Block[draw=red,fill=[RGB]{204,204,255},rounded-corners]{2-2}
    {\LARGE Some beautiful flowers}
    & & marigold \\
    iris & & & lis \\
    arum & periwinkle & forget-me-not & hyacinth
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

The logs show I have `Package: nicematrix 2020/02/07 v3.11 Mathematical matrices with TikZ`. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal) with TexLive 2019 (as per my package manager).

Comment: your nicematrix version is too old. In texlive 2021 your document compiles.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to update my system or fiddle with a manual install because of one package. I'll use something else instead. Thanks!

Comment: More detailed info: `NiceTabular` env is available since `nicematrix` v4.0, [released on 2020-05-08](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.520.1589129970.3866.ctan-ann@ctan.org).

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time I also **don't want** to install a new package on my stable production installation.

But sometimes you want to try a new package or see if an update solves a problem.

Many times you can follow this recipe.

1. Download `nicematrix.zip` from the CTAN site [nicematrix.zip](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix.zip)
2. Put the `nicematrix` directory found the `.zip` in your working
   directory. Inside you will find the manual and the files
   `nicematrix.dtx` and `nicematrix.ins`.
3. Open a command window in that `nicematrix` subdirectoy and type at
   the command prompt:
   `pdflatex micematrix.ins`
4. It will unpack the `.dtx` file and generate `nicematrix.sty`.
5. Copy this file to the working directory and rename it
   `nicematrix63.sty`. I used 63 because the current release is the
   6.3, but any other number will do.
6. Finally include `\usepackage{nicematrix63}` in you preamble.

The example will compile properly. (with a `LaTeX Warning: You have requested package nicematrix63, but the package provides nicematrix`).

Adding  `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{article}` will list all the files loaded. At the end of the `.log` you will find

`nicematrix63.sty    2021/10/18 v6.3 Enhanced arrays with the help of PGF/TikZ`

```
\listfiles

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix63} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cwc{2cm}wc{3cm}c}
        rose & tulip & daisy & dahlia \\
        violet
        & \Block[draw=red,fill=[RGB]{204,204,255},rounded-corners]{2-2}
        {\LARGE Some beautiful flowers}
        & & marigold \\
        iris & & & lis \\
        arum & periwinkle & forget-me-not & hyacinth
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```